# Explaining postfix entries in syslog

Tags: postfix, log-files

My `syslog` is absolutely crammed with `postfix` messages like :

```
Jun 28 10:27:07 myserver postfix/smtpd[28830]: connect from unknown[180.215.170.141]
Jun 28 10:27:07 myserver postfix/smtpd[28830]: match_list_match: unknown: no match
Jun 28 10:27:07 myserver postfix/smtpd[28830]: match_list_match: 180.215.170.141: no match
Jun 28 10:27:07 myserver postfix/smtpd[28830]: match_list_match: unknown: no match
Jun 28 10:27:07 myserver postfix/smtpd[28830]: match_list_match: 180.215.170.141: no match
Jun 28 10:27:07 myserver postfix/smtpd[28830]: smtp_stream_setup: maxtime=300 enable_deadline=0
Jun 28 10:27:07 myserver postfix/smtpd[28830]: match_hostname: unknown ~? 127.0.0.0/8
Jun 28 10:27:07 myserver postfix/smtpd[28830]: match_hostaddr: 180.215.170.141 ~? 127.0.0.0/8
Jun 28 10:27:07 myserver postfix/smtpd[28830]: match_hostname: unknown ~? [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104
Jun 28 10:27:07 myserver postfix/smtpd[28830]: match_hostaddr: 180.215.170.141 ~? [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104
Jun 28 10:27:07 myserver postfix/smtpd[28830]: match_hostname: unknown ~? [::1]/128
Jun 28 10:27:07 myserver postfix/smtpd[28830]: match_hostaddr: 180.215.170.141 ~? [::1]/128
Jun 28 10:27:07 myserver postfix/smtpd[28830]: match_list_match: unknown: no match
Jun 28 10:27:07 myserver postfix/smtpd[28830]: match_list_match: 180.215.170.141: no match
Jun 28 10:27:07 myserver postfix/smtpd[28830]: send attr request = connect
Jun 28 10:27:07 myserver postfix/smtpd[28830]: send attr ident = smtp:180.215.170.141
Jun 28 10:27:07 myserver postfix/smtpd[28830]: private/anvil: wanted attribute: status
Jun 28 10:27:07 myserver postfix/smtpd[28830]: input attribute name: status
Jun 28 10:27:07 myserver postfix/smtpd[28830]: input attribute value: 0
Jun 28 10:27:07 myserver postfix/smtpd[28830]: private/anvil: wanted attribute: count
Jun 28 10:27:07 myserver postfix/smtpd[28830]: input attribute name: count
Jun 28 10:27:07 myserver postfix/smtpd[28830]: input attribute value: 1
Jun 28 10:27:07 myserver postfix/smtpd[28830]: private/anvil: wanted attribute: rate
Jun 28 10:27:07 myserver postfix/smtpd[28830]: input attribute name: rate
Jun 28 10:27:07 myserver postfix/smtpd[28830]: input attribute value: 21
Jun 28 10:27:07 myserver postfix/smtpd[28830]: private/anvil: wanted attribute: (list terminator)
Jun 28 10:27:07 myserver postfix/smtpd[28830]: input attribute name: (end)
Jun 28 10:27:07 myserver postfix/smtpd[28830]: > unknown[180.215.170.141]: 220 myserver.mydomain.co.uk ESMTP Postfix (Ubuntu)
Jun 28 10:27:07 myserver postfix/smtpd[28830]: < unknown[180.215.170.141]: EHLO ylmf-pc
Jun 28 10:27:07 myserver postfix/smtpd[28830]: match_list_match: unknown: no match
Jun 28 10:27:07 myserver postfix/smtpd[28830]: match_list_match: 180.215.170.141: no match
Jun 28 10:27:07 myserver postfix/smtpd[28830]: > unknown[180.215.170.141]: 250-myserver.mydomain.co.uk
Jun 28 10:27:07 myserver postfix/smtpd[28830]: > unknown[180.215.170.141]: 250-PIPELINING
Jun 28 10:27:07 myserver postfix/smtpd[28830]: > unknown[180.215.170.141]: 250-SIZE 10240000
Jun 28 10:27:07 myserver postfix/smtpd[28830]: > unknown[180.215.170.141]: 250-VRFY
Jun 28 10:27:07 myserver postfix/smtpd[28830]: > unknown[180.215.170.141]: 250-ETRN
Jun 28 10:27:07 myserver postfix/smtpd[28830]: > unknown[180.215.170.141]: 250-STARTTLS
Jun 28 10:27:07 myserver postfix/smtpd[28830]: > unknown[180.215.170.141]: 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
Jun 28 10:27:07 myserver postfix/smtpd[28830]: > unknown[180.215.170.141]: 250-8BITMIME
Jun 28 10:27:07 myserver postfix/smtpd[28830]: > unknown[180.215.170.141]: 250 DSN
Jun 28 10:27:08 myserver postfix/smtpd[28830]: < unknown[180.215.170.141]: AUTH LOGIN
Jun 28 10:27:08 myserver postfix/smtpd[28830]: > unknown[180.215.170.141]: 503 5.5.1 Error: authentication not enabled
Jun 28 10:27:08 myserver postfix/smtpd[28830]: smtp_get: EOF
Jun 28 10:27:08 myserver postfix/smtpd[28830]: match_hostname: unknown ~? 127.0.0.0/8
Jun 28 10:27:08 myserver postfix/smtpd[28830]: match_hostaddr: 180.215.170.141 ~? 127.0.0.0/8
Jun 28 10:27:08 myserver postfix/smtpd[28830]: match_hostname: unknown ~? [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104
Jun 28 10:27:08 myserver postfix/smtpd[28830]: match_hostaddr: 180.215.170.141 ~? [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104
Jun 28 10:27:08 myserver postfix/smtpd[28830]: match_hostname: unknown ~? [::1]/128
Jun 28 10:27:08 myserver postfix/smtpd[28830]: match_hostaddr: 180.215.170.141 ~? [::1]/128
Jun 28 10:27:08 myserver postfix/smtpd[28830]: match_list_match: unknown: no match
Jun 28 10:27:08 myserver postfix/smtpd[28830]: match_list_match: 180.215.170.141: no match
Jun 28 10:27:08 myserver postfix/smtpd[28830]: send attr request = disconnect
Jun 28 10:27:08 myserver postfix/smtpd[28830]: send attr ident = smtp:180.215.170.141
Jun 28 10:27:08 myserver postfix/smtpd[28830]: private/anvil: wanted attribute: status
Jun 28 10:27:08 myserver postfix/smtpd[28830]: input attribute name: status
Jun 28 10:27:08 myserver postfix/smtpd[28830]: input attribute value: 0
Jun 28 10:27:08 myserver postfix/smtpd[28830]: private/anvil: wanted attribute: (list terminator)
Jun 28 10:27:08 myserver postfix/smtpd[28830]: input attribute name: (end)
Jun 28 10:27:08 myserver postfix/smtpd[28830]: lost connection after AUTH from unknown[180.215.170.141]
Jun 28 10:27:08 myserver postfix/smtpd[28830]: disconnect from unknown[180.215.170.141]
Jun 28 10:27:08 myserver postfix/smtpd[28830]: master_notify: status 1
Jun 28 10:27:08 myserver postfix/smtpd[28830]: connection closed
```

Is this just a bot trying (and failing) to gain access? Could anyone explain the various pieces to me? what is going on with the `match_list_match` and `match_hostname` bits?

Why are these logs cluttering syslog, rather than just being in the dedicated `mail.log`?

Comment: I have answered your first question below. For the second one (about logging), please provide the output of `postconf -n` and contents of your syslog configuration file

Comment: Thanks. I think I figured out the logging anyway, I edited to `*.*;auth,authpriv.none;mail.none;mail.error -/var/log/syslog` in `/etc/rsyslog.d/50-default.conf`, and it seems to have done the trick.

Comment: And block the muppet in your firewall, or with fail2ban or hosts.deny
ALL: 180.215.170.141

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A PC [from India](http://myip.ms/view/ip_addresses/3034032640/180.215.170.0_180.215.170.255) gone rogue and connect your server. That bot is too stupid, so it is trying to auth himself. Unfortunately, your server doesn't announce AUTH capability so postfix throws error `503 5.5.1 Error: authentication not enabled`. So it disconnect from your server and go on next victim server. Nothing to worry about.

And for second question about syslog, the OP stated that edited line

```
*.*;auth,authpriv.none;mail.none;mail.error -/var/log/syslog
```

in `/etc/rsyslog.d/50-default.conf` will make log go to maillog instead syslog.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the syslog destination config... you seem to have activated Postfix debug output (with `debug_peer_list`). Do yourself a favour and disable that, then you will get 3-5 log lines instead of 100 lines per connection.

Comment: I'm not sure, it was a while ago when I set this up. I checked `/etc/postfix/main.conf` and could not see any mention of word `debug`. Where would I have set this?

Comment: Hmm, maybe it's the `smtpd -v` in the `master.conf`?

Comment: Adding argument `-v` into smtpd will cause smtpd process produce verbose logging. See [Making Postfix daemon programs more verbose](http://www.postfix.org/DEBUG_README.html#verbose)